# "setState is not defined" thrown when using 3rd party React Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, bottom-sheet

I'm new to React and want to integrate it into an existing application to update the UI to material design (for transpilling and building the application I'm using Babel and webpack). Amongst other things I wanted to integrate a bottomsheet component provided by [material-ui-bottom-sheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-bottom-sheet). However, while the component shows up in my application as expected the callbacks for setting the component's state (and thereby its visibility) result in

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: setState is not defined
at onRequestClose (verwaltung.js?8a80:70)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js?8875:69)
at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js?5685:85)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js?5685:108)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (EventPluginHub.js?3c44:43)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (EventPluginHub.js?3c44:54)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEachAccumulated (forEachAccumulated.js?2859:24)
at Object.processEventQueue (EventPluginHub.js?3c44:254)
at runEventQueueInBatch (ReactEventEmitterMixin.js?9870:17)
```

Since I copied the code from the official example site (https://teamwertarbyte.github.io/material-ui-bottom-sheet/) where working examples are provided I'm wondering what causes this behaviour and why this isn't working for me. 
The relevant code of my application for showing the component is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
[...]
<div id="bottom-sheet"></div>
[...]
```

**Javascript:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

// Bottom sheet
import { ExpandableBottomSheet, BottomSheet } from 'material-ui-bottom-sheet';
import { List, ListItem, Subheader, FloatingActionButton } from 'material-ui';
import MapsDirectionsCar from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/done';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

const InfoSheet = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
            <ExpandableBottomSheet
                action={
                    <FloatingActionButton>
                        <MapsDirectionsCar/>
                    </FloatingActionButton>
                }
                onRequestClose={() => setState({isOpen: false})}
                open
            >
                <h1 style={{marginLeft: 72, marginTop: 40}}>Dandelion Chocolate</h1>
                <Divider inset/>
                <List>
                    <ListItem primaryText="740 Valencia St, San Francisco, CA"/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="(415) 349-0942"/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Wed, 10 AM - 9 PM"/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="740 Valencia St, San Francisco, CA"/>
                </List>
            </ExpandableBottomSheet>
        </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <InfoSheet />,
    document.getElementById('bottom-sheet')
);
```

If I try to set the **"open"** property to **"{state.isOpen}"** the application throws another error which says that **"state"** is undefined.

What am I missing here and why are **setState** and **state** not in the Component's scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your InfoSheet component is a stateless component which do not have `lifecycle functions`, `state` or `this` keyword. Write InfoSheet component to extend React.Component class as

```
class InfoSheet extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {isOpen: true}
 }
 render() {
    return (
       <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
            <ExpandableBottomSheet
                action={
                    <FloatingActionButton>
                        <MapsDirectionsCar/>
                    </FloatingActionButton>
                }
                onRequestClose={() => this.setState({isOpen: false})}
                open={this.state.isOpen}
            >
                <h1 style={{marginLeft: 72, marginTop: 40}}>Dandelion Chocolate</h1>
                <Divider inset/>
                <List>
                    <ListItem primaryText="740 Valencia St, San Francisco, CA"/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="(415) 349-0942"/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="Wed, 10 AM - 9 PM"/>
                    <ListItem primaryText="740 Valencia St, San Francisco, CA"/>
                </List>
            </ExpandableBottomSheet>
        </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you very much! after setting the "open" property to {this.state.isOpen} it finally works like a charm!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped

Comment: @Sulthan, thanks for correcting, I just got confused between the terminologies, just corrected it though

Comment: The functional components are also often referred as *stateless* components.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have corrected myself. It seems React is changing the naming often :) Both names are probably correct but in this case *stateless* really explains the problem.

Comment: I saw your corrected comment and yes I was also trying to find a documentation where react has explained it properly to add it to answer for reference